# error in NULL value and finding tgt tables in Merge

Tags: postgresql

I have already worked in Oracle. and my merge statements doesn't work in postgres.

whole scenario is:

I have 2 schemas in  postgres DB, exactly the same tables into both schemas, first schemas has data in its table and schema 2 is empty for now.Data inserted every 8 hours in first schema from the source. I want to tranfer data from first schema to second one (by using trigger) and then truncate the tables of first schma.  I wrote merge statement but I get two errors

1. null value

it doesn't accept

```
coalesce (tgt.movie_length,'NULL')= coalesce (src.movie_length,'NULL')
```

if I change it to

```
coalesce (tgt.movie_length,NULL)= coalesce (src.movie_length, NULL).
```

it goes further

in oracle I write 'NULL' for null value

```
NVL(tgt.movie_length,'NULL')= NVL(src.movie_length,'NULL')
```

2. after

```
 when matched then update set
 tgt.movie_id =src.movie_id
```

error is:  column "tgt" of relation "movies" does not exist

why it has problem with tgt

```
merge into second_schema.movies as tgt 
using (select 
movie_id
,movie_name
,movie_length
,movie_lang 
,age_certificate 
,release_date 
,director_id 
from public.movies  
) src 
on (
    coalesce (tgt.movie_length,NULL)= coalesce (src.movie_length,NULL)
and coalesce (tgt.movie_lang,NULL)= coalesce (src.movie_lang,NULL)
and coalesce (tgt.age_certificate,NULL)= coalesce (src.age_certificate,NULL)
and coalesce (tgt.release_date ,NULL) = coalesce (src.release_date, NULL)
--and coalesce (tgt.director_id, NULL)= coalesce (src.director_id, NULL)
)
when matched then update set
tgt.movie_id =src.movie_id -------> error: column "tgt" of relation "movies" does not exist
,tgt.movie_name=src.movie_id 
,tgt.movie_length=src.movie_length 
,tgt.movie_lang =src.movie_lang 
,tgt.age_certificate =src.age_certificate 
,tgt.release_date =src.release_date 
,tgt.director_id =src.director_id
```

How should be 'NULL' and why it doesnt recognise tgt after update?

Comment: It may be way easier for us to understand, if you can describe your problem and present sample input data and expected output, to be solved in postgresql, rather than trying to do a 1:1 match with an oracle query, with no knowledge about what we're dealing with. In the best scenario, your query may even get simplified.

Comment: Remove the `tgt.` from the left side of the `UPDATE`'s e.g. `movie_id =src.movie_id, movie_name=src.movie_id , etc.` Per [Merge](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html): *MERGE actions have the same effect as regular UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE commands of the same names. The syntax of those commands is different, notably that there is no WHERE clause and no table name is specified. All actions refer to the target_table_name, though modifications to other tables may be made using triggers.*.